# Discord.py How to check if user get a new role?

Tags: discord.py

I want that when a user gets a **certain** role, the bot will write an embed message to a **certain** channel

I tried to use

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
    channel_id = yyyyyyyyyyyyy 

    role = before.guild.get_role(role_id)
    channel = before.guild.get_channel(channel_id)

    if role and channel:
        roles_before = set(role.id for role in before.roles)
        roles_after = set(role.id for role in after.roles)

        if role.id in roles_after and role.id not in roles_before:
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{after.mention} have now this role, cool!", color=(28, 60, 128))
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

But it doesn't work. When adding a role, the bot doesn't write anything. What's wrong there?

Comment: Did you enable the members Intent?

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before:discord.Member,after:discord.Member):
    role = before.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    channel = before.guild.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
        await channel.send("Role added")
```

Comment: I tried it, but nothing works. The bot doesn't write anything in response to a user getting a role.

Comment: Please explain your code. Simply posting a code without explanation is not really helpful.

Comment: @Flichendery Then you got something wrong. I tested the code and it works for me just fine.

Comment: @Dominik For anyone with a little bit of knowledge of python and discord.py this code is self explanatory let alone if someone is working on a project with member updates.

Comment: Truth be told, most people will simply copy the code and paste it into theirs without any knowledge of how it works. In answering questions, we should aim to seek the poster's understanding and help them to start being more knowledgeable about the subject. In this way, they will be able to solve more of their own problems on their own, instead of leaving them completely clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can find answer. This is what I wanted:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before:discord.Member, after:discord.Member):
    role = before.guild.get_role(xxxxxxx)
    channel = before.guild.get_channel(xxxxxx)
    gif_url = "xxxxx"
    if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
      embed = discord.Embed(
            color = discord.Color.from_rgb(28, 60, 128))
      embed.set_image(url=gif_url)
      await channel.send(f'<@{after.id}> **get role, cool!**', embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**